# tf.gatherとtf.expand_dimsはどういう意味でしょうか？

Tags: python, tensorflow

tf.gatherとtf.expand_dimsはどういう意味でしょうか？
公式サイトを見ましたがよくわかりませんでした。

```
top_k_xvals, top_k_indices = tf.nn.top_k(tf.negative(distance), k=k)

x_sums = tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_sum(top_k_xvals, 1),1)
x_sums_repeated = tf.matmul(x_sums, tf.ones([1, k], tf.float32))
x_val_weights = tf.expand_dims(tf.div(top_k_xvals,x_sums_repeated), 1)

top_k_yvals = tf.gather(y_target_train, top_k_indices)
prediction = tf.squeeze(tf.matmul(x_val_weights, top_k_yvals), axis=[1])
```

参照：TensorFlow機械学習クックブック

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tf.expand_dims(input, axis) は input テンソルの axis に指定した階に 1 次元挿入する．

e.g. shape が (2,3,4) の input の axis=2 に 1 次元を挿入すると (2,3,1,4) になる．

PyTorch でいう unsqueeze と同じ．

~~

tf.gather(params, indices, axis) は params テンソルの axis に指定した階でスライスして，indeices で指定したインデックスのテンソルだけ取り出してくっつける．

e.g. [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] という params テンソルの axis=1 でスライスすると [1,4] と [2,5] と [3,6] という 3 つのテンソルができ，indeces=[1,2] なら 1,2 番目のテンソルを取り出してくっつけるので [[2,3],[5,6]] になる．